# Acumatica-LotSerialNbrAttribute screen on mobile app

Tags: customization, acumatica

I'm using Acumatica customization [Acumatica-LotSerialNbrAttribute](https://github.com/Acumatica/Acumatica-LotSerialNbrAttribute)

This customization adds a new screen for look for InventoryID and LotSerialNbr and visualize its attributes.

[image: IN202501]

I'm trying to add this window to the acumatica mobile app.
Here my code:

```
add screen IN202501 {
  add container "InventoryLotSerialContainers" {
    add field "InventoryID"
    add field "LotSerialNbr"    
    add group "Attributes" {
      displayName = "Attributes"
      collapsable = True
      add attributes "AttributesAttributes"
    }
    add recordAction "Save" {
      behavior = Save
    }
    add recordAction "Cancel" {
      behavior = Cancel
    }
    attachments {
    }
  }
}
```

And the screen is visible on the mobile app with the 2 selectors
Then I select Inventory and when I select Lot Serial Nbr, the first selector is in blank, causing that I can't review the attributtes neither save the information.

[image: Mobile screen 1]

Here the InventoryID selector in blank.
[image: Mobile screen 2]

Hope you can help me to successfully publish this screen on acumatica mobile app.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Attributes are a grid style representation in Acumatica.  That means you need a container that will show multiple records.  I'm getting rusty on mobile pretty quickly, but I believe your definition is set to display a single value value only.

Try adding a separate container for attributes:

```
add container "AttributesAttributes" {
  add field "Attribute"
  add field "Value"
}
```

This should open into a view of multiple records, showing all of your attributes.  By specifying the Attribute and Value fields, you should see both data elements in the container.

Comment: Initially I added the mobile screen without attributes, just InventoryID and LotSerialNbr fields, and the behavior is the same without the whole section.